# Admin rights not enough to delete a file?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

So I am learning C++, and am using Sublime Text 3. I have made a program, which I can't delete for some reason, even with **administrator** rights.

[image: This picture of a terminal session depicts my problem]

And that was with **admin** rights. So, I am a bit worried right now. Am I missing something important?

Details:

- I use MinGW for g++ (to compile)
- Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: Try to delete after reboot. If not success, take a look of security tab in the file property menu.

Answer (score 0):

Administrator rights are **always** enough on NTFS volumes.

Members of the computer's built-in Administrators group have the right to take ownership of any filesystem object. An object's owner always has the right to set whatever permissions he wishes, including the right to add permissions for himself even if none were granted before. By this process Administrators are always able to grant themselves access to any file or folder.

As indicated by your comment the problem was simply that the file was in use when you attempted to delete it:

> I was running it in Sublime Text while I tried to remove it....*facepalm*.

*That* condition indeed prevents the file from being deleted. In fact, it's a technique often leveraged by malware to thwart attempts by an administrator to remove it.

Comment: "In fact, it's a technique often leveraged by malware to thwart attempts by an administrator to remove it.", clever technique.